# Symfony3 + AWS Redshift

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I was able to connect to Aws Redshift in my Symfony3 project. Successfully created table and made query from Symfony to insert any data in that table. For me is problem to get data from database. I'm trying to execute query like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

and the issue is that i always get empty array.
Could u help me to solve in plan of Symfony or clear php.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you successfully inserted data on your Database? It may be that it is still empty

Comment: I'm using Navicat for PostgreSQL GUI and there i can see one record.